# How do I tell Google my search terms are requirements and not mere suggestions?

Tags: google-search

I've noticed Google is ignoring some of my search terms. It has been happening for a while but I can't recall when it started. For example, below I am trying to find processor specs for a MIPS I-class 6500 cpu to see if it supports MIPS SIMD Architecture (MSA). Google removed my search term *specs* so I got irrelevant junk back instead of technical information.

I can't guess which terms Google is going to ignore in advance so I need to each word in quotes. We don't read and write with every word in quotes and it makes no sense to do it here. It is also extra typing and wastes time.

I've also noticed it when searching Google images for famous people. Google will throw extraneous results in when searching for people like *"Stephen Lang"*. In this case Google is given the full name but returns partial matches, like people with first name Stephen or last name Lang. In this case everything is in quotes and there is no ambiguity.

How do I tell Google my search terms are requirements and not mere suggestions?

---

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the advanced search?

Comment: Thanks @Rubén. No, I use Google like shown above. I'd like to have Google match my workflow. I don't want to do something special to get search results based on my terms. Is their a profile setting somewhere to fix it? I don't want to switch search engines, but I've been thinking about it more and more as Google ignores more of my terms and returns worse results.

Comment: See https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

To tell Google that search terms are requirements and not mere suggestions, put them in double-quotes.

For example:   mips i6500 cpu "specs"

But beware - do you want specs, or specifications?