# How to fix a broken Google search?

Tags: google-search

I think this is related to broken Google search at [How do I tell Google my search terms are requirements and not mere suggestions?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/121540/72479). I think this question is a particular case of the general problem.

I need to search for the terms ***c++ implicit template instantiation -flto***. Because ***-flto*** has a dash I quote it ***"-flto"***. Search is not honoring my quotes and omits the term, but asks me if it should be included by further quoting the quoted term which has already been quoted twice. Ad infinitum:

[image]

How do I enter my terms so Google provides search results for them?

Answer (score -1):

you can try to fix it with **`*`** like:

> **`c++ implicit template instantiation "*-flto"`**

[image: 2]

Comment: Oh that's nice. Where did the asterisk come from?

Comment: @jww since I known google asterisk was always a wildcard operator like in many other pc languages - https://ahrefs.com/blog/google-advanced-search-operators/